# Comparison operator not working

Tags: filemaker

I am using FileMaker Web Publishing Engine version="12.0.2.228 and can't quite get the comparison operators to work

e.g. I am executing the following

when I do

```
fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=MY_TESTING&-lay=MY_SUBJECTS&name_short=Yr10&-find
```

I get two results (as expected because the default filemaker query is beings with)

Record 1) name_short = Yr10

Record 2) name_short = Yr10-TO

However when I excute with a eq comparision would expect only record 1 to return. I get the same two records back

```
fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=MY_TESTING&-lay=MY_SUBJECTS&name_short=Yr10&name_short.op=eq&-find
```

results in

Record 1) name_short = Yr10

Record 2) name_short = Yr10-TO

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try the same search in FileMaker, and you'll see consistent results. The answer is to prefix your search term with "==" for an exact match.

```
fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=MY_TESTING&-lay=MY_SUBJECTS&name_short=%3D%3DYr10&-find
```